# How to access SQL Server in host from docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, hyper-v, windows-container

#### What I have

- default instance of SQL Server running or my Windows 11 laptop. I connect to it using Server=localhost or Server=MyComputerName
- web backend running in a windows container.

#### Question

How do I connect from the container to the host's sql server?

Ideal solution (powershell/dockercompose) would work on other PCs with the same setup except ComputerName.